# Is there a name for a function or field of position and rotation?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, field-theory, coordinate-systems

A scalar field is a function which has a different value at all positions e.g. $\phi(x)$ where $x$ is a 3-vector.

Imagine that the value of a field depended not only on the position of a detector but it's orientation. That is the field depended on the position $x$ and an orthogonal rotation matrix $r$. Is there a name for such a field $\phi(x,r)$? In 3 dimensions it would depend on 3+3=6 variables and in 4 dimensions it would depend on 4+6=10 variables.

Some things I noticed about such a field is that it would transform under a change of coordinates as:

$\phi(x,r) \rightarrow \phi\left(x',\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}.r\right)$

And also, that if you made a Taylor series in terms of $r$ you get an infinite set of tensors. So it is not a tensor itself but contains lots of tensors.

So I wondered, is there a name for such a field? Have there been any physics theories using fields like this?

**Edit:** just realised that this would not work under an arbitrary coordinate transformation as this would not produce a pure rotation matrix. You might have to allow all affine matrices.

Comment: You are not looking for an antisymmetric tensor field, are you?

Comment: nope just the name of the function above  (if it has one) which depends on 6 variables in 3D. Any tensor field depends only on 3 variables in 3D.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but I disagree. What you are writing does, strictly speaking, make no sense, at least not in a rotational invariant theory such as a theory formulated in 3D Euclidean or 4D Minkowski space. There is no such thing as relative rotation to Minkowski space, However, your detector could have a spin, say, and you can measure the relative orientation of a tensor field w.r.t. to this spin.

Comment: OK, it might not make sense if you put those restrictions on it. But it does theoretically make sense. It would be an extension to Minkowski space that did have relative rotation in this model Universe. Also, try expanding the field in terms of r. You get a series of perfectly reasonable tensor fields.

Comment: Fine. So you are looking at a space with a preferred direction and asking for the name? You might consider a ferromagnet, in which there is such a direction, and look at excitations there. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: In screw theory this is called a helical field. It describes the motion of a rigid body in 3D using 6 variables.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking at a scalar field $\Phi$ in 3-D Euclidian space whose value depends both on position vector $\vec r$ and the local direction in space corresponding to the orientation of a detector. I quote you : *"Imagine that the value of a field depended not only on the position of a detector but it's orientation."* A direction in space is determined by only 2 independent parameters (e.g., $\theta$ and $\phi$ of polar coordinates). You don't need an orthogonal rotation matrix with 3 independent parameters to define the direction. Thus, this field depends only on 5 independent variables not on 6 as you posited. The result is just a scalar field in the 5-dimensional space given by the the 3-D position vector and the two parameters defining direction in 3-D space: $\Phi(x, y, z, \theta, \phi)$.

After the clarification by the OP (see his comments) that by local "orientation" he meant a local rotation, which depends on 3 parameters, it is obvious that the scalar field has 6 parameters $$\Phi(x,y,z, \alpha, \beta, \gamma) \tag 1$$ where the last three parameters are, e.g., Euler's angles. Such a 6 parameters configuration space is common in the description of the [dynamics of a rigid solid body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics#Orientation_vector) and the 6 parameters can be considered to be generalized coordinates $q_1,q_2,...q_6$ that can be used in the description of the solid body dynamics, e.g., in the framework of the Euler-Lagrange equations. When the forces on the body are conservative, these generalized forces $Q_i(q_1,q_2,...,q_6)$ can be described by the gradient in configuration space of a generalized potential function $$\Phi(x,y,z,\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\Phi(q_1,q_2,...,q_6) \tag 2$$ $$Q_i=-\frac {\partial \Phi}{\partial q_i} \tag 3$$ This generalized potential function eq. (2) is a practical example of a scalar function that depends both on the 3 cartesian coordinates (here the center of gravity of the body) and on the 3 local rotation parameters. In this case, the name of this scalar function of the 3 position and 3 rotation parameters is generalized scalar potential.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. A direction is indeed given by 2 parameters. But an orientation by 3. Think of an aeroplane it has yaw, pitch and roll. It doesn't just matter which direction the aeroplanes nose is pointing but, for example, if the aeroplane is flying upside down!

Comment: @zooby - What do you mean by the "orientation of a detector"? Yaw,  pitch and roll are the 3 independent parameters determining the general rotation of an object in space.

Comment: Think of a detector as a little box which gives the value of the field at it's center. You can move the detector to any point and orient the detector at any rotation. It's just a thought experiment. I don't mean a physical detector.

Comment: @zooby - What physical quantity do you have in mind that such a detector should measure?

Comment: Who knows! But it is not impossible to imagine such a detector. And then the field would depend on 6 variables instead of 3. As I said you could expand the field in terms of lots of tensors. So it would measure a combination of tensor fields I presume.

Comment: But good point about the 3 extra dimensions being a compact space.

Comment: @zooby - In my expanded answer, I have given an example for a scalar potential function depending on the 3 position coordinates and the 3 rotation parameters in the dynamics of a rigid solid body in a conservative force field.